# Why does an internal value react to changes from the whole ref?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have an object ...

```
export class Note {
  type = ''
  id: string = v4()
  creationDate: string = DateTime.now().toISO()
  modificationDate: string = DateTime.now().toISO()
  text = ''
  title = ''
  tags: string[] = []
  deleted = false
  deletedAt?: string = ''
  erased = false
  erasedAt?: string = ''
  archived = false
  archivedAt?: string = ''
  deleteOn?: string = ''
  pinned = false
  // methods follow
}
```

... that I pass as a prop to a component

```
<script lang='ts' setup>

const props = defineProps({
  currentNote: {type: Object, default: () => {return {}}},
})

const note = toRef(props, 'currentNote') as Ref<Note>

const toWatch = computed(() => [toRef(note, 'title'), toRef(note, 'text'), toRef(note, 'tags'), toRef(note, 'type')])
watch(toWatch, debounce(() => {console.log(JSON.stringify(note)); note.value.writeToOffline()}, 1000), {deep: true})

(...)
```

What happens, however, is that the `watch` callback gets triggered **whenever any property of `note` changes**.

The construction above was to only watch selected properties, but apparently they carry any change.

What is wrong with the logic in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not reproducible. Check demo below...

1. Changes to `archived` do not trigger watcher
2. Changes to `title` **also do not trigger** watcher - note the code inside `toWatch` computed - the code is same as in your example: `Vue.toRef(note, 'title')`
3. Changes to `text` triggers the watcher - To fix problem above, you need to use `Vue.toRef(note.value, 'text')` eg. to pass a ref value instead of ref itself to `toRefs`

All this works without `{deep: true}` because `watch` can watch an array of refs (and as it seems also `ref` containing array of `refs`)

```js
class Note {
    constructor() {
        this.type = '';
        this.id = 'asdsad';
        this.text = 'text';
        this.title = 'title';
        this.tags = [];
        this.deleted = false;
        this.deletedAt = '';
        this.erased = false;
        this.erasedAt = '';
        this.archived = false;
        this.archivedAt = '';
        this.deleteOn = '';
        this.pinned = false;
    }
}

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup(){
    const note = Vue.reactive(new Note())
    
    const modifyArchived = function() {
      note.archived = !note.archived
    }
    const modifyTitle = function() {
      note.title = note.title + '+'
    }
    const modifyText = function() {
      note.text = note.text + '+'
    }

    return {
      note,
      modifyArchived,
      modifyTitle,
      modifyText
    }
  },
})

app.component('child', {
  props: ['currentNote'],
  setup(props) {
    const note = Vue.toRef(props, 'currentNote')
    const changes = Vue.ref(0)

    const toWatch = Vue.computed(() => [Vue.toRef(note, 'title'), Vue.toRef(note.value, 'text'), Vue.toRef(note, 'tags'), Vue.toRef(note, 'type')])
    Vue.watch(toWatch, () => { changes.value++ } /*, {deep: true} */)

    return { 
      note,
      changes
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>Child: (changes = {{ changes }})</div>
    <div>archived: {{ note.archived }}</div>
    <div>title: {{ note.title }}</div>
    <div>text: {{ note.text }}</div>    
    `
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.23/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div>Parent:</div>
  <div><button @click="modifyArchived">Modify archived (no trigger)</button></div>
  <div><button @click="modifyTitle">Modify title (no trigger - not ok!)</button></div>
  <div><button @click="modifyText">Modify text (trigger - ok!)</button></div>
  
  <child :current-note="note"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified your example (https://jsfiddle.net/WoJWoJ/Lsp67vqo/) to exactly reproduce my problem (a non-watched property that triggers the watch callback anyway) and I cannot reproduce it. I have to look again at my code because it must be something over there. Thank you for reminding me about using `.value` in the `toRef()`.